# How can I extract elements from lists of lists in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a bunch of lists containing lists within them (generalised linear model output).  I want to write a function which will extract several elements from each list and then combine the results into a data frame.

I want to  extract `modelset[[1]]$likelihood` & `modelset[[1]]$fixef`, `modelset[[2]]$likelihood` & `modelset[[2]]$fixef`, etc, and combine the results into a data frame.

Can someone give me an idea of how to do this?

Apologies if my question is confusing: what I am trying to do is beyond my limited programming understanding.

Further information about my list:

```
modelset: Large list (16 elements, 7.3Mb)
    :List of 29
    ..$ fixef           : Named num [1:2] -1.236 -0.611
    .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "SMIstd"
    ..$ likelihood      :List of 4
    .. ..$ hlik: num 238
    .. ..$ pvh : num 256
    .. ..$ pbvh: num 260
    .. ..$ cAIC: num 567

    ...etc
```

Comment: `lapply( modelset , "[[" , "likelihood" )` etc...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In order to solve this elegantly you need to understand that you can use `['…']` instead of `$…` to access list elements (but you will get a list back instead of an individual element).

So if you want to get the elements `likelihood` and `fixef`, you can write:

```
modelset[[1]][c('likelihood', 'fixef')]
```

Now you want to do that for each element in `modelset`. That’s what [`lapply`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) does:

```
lapply(modelset, function (x) x[c('likelihood', 'fixef')])
```

This works, but it’s not very R-like.

You see, in R, almost **everything** is a function. `[…]` is calling a function named `[` (but since `[` is a special symbol for R, in needs to be quoted in backticks: `` `[` ``). So you can instead write this:

```
lapply(modelset, function (x) `[`(x, c('likelihood', 'fixef')))
```

Wow, that’s not very readable at all. However, we can now remove the wrapping anonymous `function (x)`, since inside we’re just calling another function, and move the extra arguments to the last parameter of `lapply`:

```
lapply(modelset, `[`, c('likelihood', 'fixef'))
```

This works and is elegant R code.

---

Let’s step back and re-examine what we did here. In effect, we had an expression which looked like this:

```
lapply(some_list, function (x) f(x, y))
```

And this call can instead be written as

```
lapply(some_list, f, y)
```

We did exactly that, with `somelist = modelset`, `` f = `[` `` and `y = c('likelihood', 'fixef')`.

Comment: It not easy to find such didatic answer like this one. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer and explanation.

Comment: The second `lapply` line has the wrong number of parentheses, and I have not been able to figure out how to fix it. Replacing the closing square bracket with a curved bracket (paren) produces the wrong output.

Comment: @randy Thanks for noticing, it was missing the `x` argument (in addition to using the wrong closing parenthesis).