# Running chi-square for multiply-imputed data / extracting estimates from a list of lists

Tags: r, lapply, r-mice

I have run `mice` to create 50 imputed datasets. Now, I am trying to compute chi-square statistics for some of my variables.

It is possible to obtain individual estimates for each dataset:

```
list <- with(imp, chisq.test(var1, var2, correct = FALSE))
```

But the results cannot be pooled. It is possible to combine the results in `miceadds`, but the function requires a vector of chi-square statistics.

How do I extract the relevant information from `list$analyses[[i]]$statistic`? I assume `lapply` would be appropriate, but I am not sure how to specify it for a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758858/how-can-i-extract-elements-from-lists-of-lists-in-r) seems to be appropriate:

```
x2 <- lapply(list$analyses, `[`, 'statistic')
x2 <- unlist(x2, use.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Whenever `lapply` and `unlist` are used back to back, you should use `sapply` or `vapply`.