# accessing a particular value from all objects within a list of objects in R

Tags: r

I have a list containing j objects. Lets call this list as X. Each object contains k items. I can access particular value(lets say 2'nd item) of an object(lets say 3'rd object) using below method.

```
X[[3]][2]
```

How do I access a list containing all the 2'nd items of each objects?

Comment: `lapply(X, function(x) x[2])` output a list containing the second items of the objects (in X).

Comment: I think you should modify the questions first, because there should be possibly duplicated questions for such kind of "extract list of list of list" questions. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758858/how-can-i-extract-elements-from-lists-of-lists-in-r)

Comment: thanks @raymkchow. Your suggestion works well. As suggested by others I will use sapply to get a simple list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 all <- list(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,3))
 lapply(all, `[[`, 2)

 $a
 [1] 2

 $b
 [1] 3
```

Comment: lapply(X, `[[`, 2)
[[1]]
[1] 0.008048156

[[2]]
[1] 0.007682355

[[3]]
[1] 0.009694033

[[4]]
[1] 0.00733318

[[5]]
[1] 0.009694033

[[6]]
[1] 0.008048156

[[7]]
[1] 0.0310138

[[8]]
[1] 0.0116765

[[9]]
[1] 0.006999876

[[10]]
[1] 0.008832842
Is it possible to get something like this: (0.008048156,0.007682355.....)

Comment: @itthrill Yes, it is. Just use `sapply(all, `[[`, 2)`. (The `s` in `sapply` means to **s**implify the output if possible.)

Comment: Maybe you could add the `sapply` version to your answer.

Comment: I hope it help, dput(unlist(lapply(all, `[[`, 2),use.names = F))  Output: c(2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(X, function(x) x[2])))
df
```