# Extract object from a list based on element name in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 94 matrices, a subset of which is shown here:

```
 > summary(full_matrix)

            Length Class  Mode   
 Alex_1         64 -none- numeric
 Alex_10      2500 -none- numeric
 Alex_11      2916 -none- numeric
 Alex_12     20736 -none- numeric
 Lily_1        441 -none- numeric
 Lily_10     57600 -none- numeric
 Lily_11     94249 -none- numeric
 Lily_12    167281 -none- numeric
 Lily_13    206116 -none- numeric
 Naima_1       169 -none- numeric
 Naima_10   209764 -none- numeric
 Naima_11   262144 -none- numeric
 Naima_12   209764 -none- numeric
 Naima_13   177241 -none- numeric
 Naima_14   143641 -none- numeric
```

I'm running some code on each of these matrices, which I can successfully do using `lapply()`. However, the code runs very slowly and it takes hours and hours to run on the full list. So I want to split up the list by element name. I have successfully done this manually using `subset_matrix <- full_matrix[1:4]`, which in this example will give:

```
 > summary(subset_matrix)
         Length Class  Mode   
 Alex_1     64  -none- numeric
 Alex_10  2500  -none- numeric
 Alex_11  2916  -none- numeric
 Alex_12 20736  -none- numeric
```

However this is clunky and will get messy if I make any changes to the previous parts of my script. What I'd like to do is select all elements containing "Alex_", "Lily_", "Naima_", etc, and create sub-lists of these. I thought [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758858/how-can-i-extract-elements-from-lists-of-lists-in-r) might work, but it gives me an empty list:

```
 > matrix_alex <- full_matrix[c("Alex_")] # subset for individual infants
 > summary(matrix_alex)
      Length Class  Mode
  <NA> 0      -none- NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Alex_"` is not a name in your list.

```
names(full_list)
# [1] "Alex_01"  "Alex_02"  "Alex_03"  "Bella_01" "Bella_02" "Bella_03"
```

You may want to use `grep` which looks up for a pattern.

```
subset_list <- full_list[grep("Alex_", names(full_list))]
# $Alex_01
# [,1]
# [1,]   NA
# 
# $Alex_02
# [,1]
# [1,]   NA
# 
# $Alex_03
# [,1]
# [1,]   NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
full_list <- list(Alex_01=matrix(),
                  Alex_02=matrix(),
                  Alex_03=matrix(),
                  Bella_01=matrix(),
                  Bella_02=matrix(),
                  Bella_03=matrix())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!